# Showing that a map is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

The exercises I am trying to solve is the following:

> For a constant $a \in R$, let $f:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ be given by
>   $$f(x,y,z)=(x-\frac{az}{\sqrt{1+z^2}},y+\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+z^2}},z)$$
>   Show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

I have managed to show that it is 1-1 an onto. But I am having a problem with showing the smoothness of $f$ and $f^{-1}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To prove $f$ is smooth, note that polynomials are always smooth. The square root function is not differentiable at $0$ but it is clear that $\sqrt{1+z^2}\geqslant 1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{R}$. Provided a function $g$ is smooth and $g$ is non-vanishing, $\dfrac{1}{g}$ is smooth. The product of two smooth functions is smooth. Use these facts to show $f$ is smooth. Not sure about $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to do the same for $f$ thanks for verifying. However, I also have no idea as to how to approach the smoothness of $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f^{-1}(x,y,z)=\left(x+\frac{az}{\sqrt{1+z^2}},y-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+z^2}},z\right)$$

You can verify that $ff^{-1}=id$ and $f^{-1}f=id$.

To show $f^{-1}$ is smooth, use the same approach as for $f$ in my comment.